# Kivy how to give all objects same basic functionality

Tags: python, inheritance, button, kivy

Lets say I create a custom Button class called MyButton. I want all created MyButtons to play the same sound when they are pressed. But I also want to add different functionality for specific buttons, for example I want some buttons to change label text, but I also want them to play that sound. Is there a way to do it with inheritance so I don't have to keep in mind that I have to add play sound functionality to every created button?

EDIT: Lets say I have a class MyButton declared as bellow:

```
class MyButton(Button):

    def generic_function_for_all_buttons(self):
        print('GENERIC FUNCTION')
```

now when I try to create a MyButton somewhere else in the code like this:

```
class TestClass(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        self.buttons = []
        self.set_layout()

    def button_action(self,button):
        button.generic_function_for_all_buttons()
        print(button.text)

    def set_layout(self):
        for i in range(0,100):
            button = MyButton(text=i)
            button.on_press = functools.partial(button_action, button)
            self.buttons.append(button)
            self.add_widget(button)
```

This is not runnable code, just a demonstration of what I want to achieve. Now each time I press MyButton from TestClass, it prints GENERIC FUNCTION and a number between 0-99 based on which button was pressed. But I had to add button.generic_function_for_all_buttons() line and I want to avoid it if possible. If each of the 100 buttons had its own different action like this:

```
def action_1(self,button):
    button.generic_function_for_all_buttons()
    print('1')
def action_2(self,button):
    button.generic_function_for_all_buttons()
    print('2')
def action_3(self,button):
    button.generic_function_for_all_buttons()
    print('3')
...
```

That button.generic_function_for_all_buttons() is 100 lines of code I want to avoid. I thought it must be possible somehow with inheritance,e.g I add on_press method to MyButton class like this:

```
class MyButton(Button):

    def on_press(self):
        print('GENERIC FUNCTION')
```

but then it simply ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

- Implement `on_touch_down` method in `class MyButton`
- Check for collision using `collide_point()` function

## Snippets

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('GENERIC FUNCTION')
            print(f"MyButton.text={self.text}")
            return True    # consumed touch and stop propagation / bubbling
        return super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class TestClass(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 20
        self.buttons = []
        self.set_layout()

    def set_layout(self):
        for i in range(0,100):
            button = MyButton(text=str(i))
            self.buttons.append(button)
            self.add_widget(button)
```

[Kivy » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> ...
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, I got to this solution as well, but I am not sure if it is the best way to do it. It seems to me like a workaround for something that should be really done differently. If no one comes up with a better answer I will satisfy with this and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a base class called MyButton and create child button classes that inherit from MyButton.

Then using Inheritance and Polymorphism you can keep the attributes & methods, such as the sound, the same across all child buttons, but have different labels without needing to have unique attributes for each child.

Polymorphism will also allow you to iterate through all the children, as the attributes have the same name.

See article linked describing this a little more:

https://www.pythonspot.com/polymorphism/

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say but I don't think it solves my problem. I understand I can declare a method (lets call it play_sound) in MyButton and then have access to it from the children of MyButton, but there is still the issue that I have to remember to call the function each time. So each time I create a new child of MyButton, I have to create a on_press action where I also call the self.play_sound() function. That is a lot of copy paste code I want to avoid in my project.

Comment: Can you post a code example of what you are working on?

Comment: Edited my original question with example of what I mean